# struct.error: pack expected 1 items for packing (got 4) while Packing string

Tags: python, string, byte, packing

I am trying to pack a string and convert it into bytes in python,
Having some trouble with the packing, was hoping for a little help.

```
values = ('BTH0')
s = struct.Struct('4s')
packed_data = s.pack(*values)
print(packed_data)
```

Error I am getting...

```
**struct.error: pack expected 1 items for packing (got 4**)
```

Comment: If you're just trying to convert to bytes, why not just `'BTH0'.encode('ascii')` (or what ever encoding is required)? You're currently passing `s.pack` 4 arguments: the string `'BTH0'` unpacked as positional arguments (the * before values), which is like calling `s.pack('B', 'T', 'H', '0')`.

Comment: If you expected `values` to be a tuple, then you're missing a comma. The parentheses do not make a tuple, but a comma does: `values = 'BTH0',` and `values = ('BTH0',)` both would create a 1-tuple.